# Image classifier with Keras not converging

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, computer-vision, keras, conv-neural-network

all. I am trying to build an image classifier with Keras (Tensorflow as backend). The objective is to separate memes from other images.

I am using the structure convolutional layers + fully connected layers with max pooling and dropouts.

The code is as following:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=conv_input_shape))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
sgd = SGD(lr=0.1, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.
compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy'])
```

The input is a matrix of shape (n, 100, 100, 3). n RGB images with resolution 100 x 100, and output labels are [1, 0] for meme and [0, 1] otherwise.

However, when I train the model, the loss won't ever decrease from the first iteration.

Is there anything off in the code?

I am thinking that meme is actually not that different from other images in many ways except that some of them have some sort of captions together with some other features.

What are some better architectures to solve a problem like this?

Comment: Can you try some smaller learning rate? e.g. 0.001. I guess your learning rate is too big. and there are some good architectures you can use in keras like `keras.applications.VGG16`.

Comment: @Craig.Li That's a good point. I have actually tried 0.1, 0.01, 0.005, and 0.001. Surprisingly, it did not change the situation. Then, I was wondering if it was a local minimum, so tried larger step size with larger momentum, but still didn't work. I will check keras website out! Thanks

Comment: You can try a smaller training/testing set in which you ensure that there are enough differences between the images with memes and the others. In that situation, you can check whether your NN is good or not and whether your data's classes are separable or not.

I also recommend to start trying with smaller NN to observe which new layers improve your results or provide a better convergence.

Comment: Try removing dropouts from layers preceding flatten(). Also use smaller dropout after flatten to begin with and then see if increasing that improves accuracy.